# Probability that a Wiener process crosses X axis before time $T$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I found a question regarding whether a process described by $dS(t)=\sigma dW(t)$ will breach a barrier of $H>S_0$, with $S_0$ being the initial level.  This should amount to determining the probability that a Wiener process with $W_0=0$ will cross the x-axis by time $T$ as far I can tell.

By the [reflection principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process)) it seems $\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{0<s<t}W(t)>a\right) = 2\mathbb{P}(W(t)>a)$, which in the case of the x-axis is 2*1/2=1.

Is this correct?  There is a further question on the distribution of the time of breaching the barrier, so I find it difficult to believe this is correct.

Comment: Your application of the reflection principle is correct, your assumption that it suffices to study crossing of the x axis (instead of an arbitrary parallel) is not. In summary, your answer so far is only correct for $S_0=0$

Comment: By the above equation, the solution would be $S(t)=S_0+\sigma \int{dW(t)}$, correct (basically the inital position + Brownian motion $\sim \int_0^T{N(0,\sigma^2)dt}$)?  If the barrier is at the initial position, then how is it not the same?

Comment: In other words, $P(max(W(t)_{0<t<T}) ) > \frac{H-S_0}{\sigma} $, but $H-S_0=0$, no?

Comment: OK sorry a bit dull here...it makes sense now that H is ANY arbitrary barrier that is greater than $S_0$ (by some unspecified amount).